# Why is a class not being added to my element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing the structure of one of my projects and I am unable to figure out why my new code is not adding a class to my element.

The original code is this

```
(function($)
{
    var $nav = $('#nav');

    var $nav_a = $nav.find('a');

    $nav_a.each(function()
    {
        var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('href'),
        $section = $(id);

        $section.scrollex(
        {
            mode: 'middle',

            enter: function()
            {
                $nav_a.removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My new code is this

```
$("#nav").find("a").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('href'),
        $section = $(id);

    $section.scrollex({
        mode: "middle",

        enter: function()
        {
            $("#nav").find("a").removeClass("active");

            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    })
});
```

The new code fails to add the class `active` to the elements in `#nav` but the original code works fine. What am I doing wrong in my new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point to the correct `this`

Update from

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```

to

```
$this.addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you assigned `$(this)` to `$this`, thus when you later use `$(this)` you are actually using `$$(this)`.

Replace the variable in the following line:

```js
$(this).addClass("active");
```

to

```js
$this.addClass("active");
```